# How to go from catch block to try block in java?

Tags: java, exception

I have some logic inside the try block. If exception arises, then I am catching the exception in the catch block.

Example

```
try{
    // line 1
}catch(SocketException se){
    // again goto try block
}
```

If control comes inside catch block then again I want to execute line 1 in try block but how to go again try block? Can we use Label?

Comment: If you want to loop back to an earlier point in your code, put your code in a loop.

Comment: You can put the code in a method and call that method from the catch resulting to execute a try again.

Comment: Depending on your situation, recursion or a nested try are also valid options, although generally much less desirable.

Comment: If SocketException arises, then I want to execute line1.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to loop back to an earlier point in your code, put your code in a loop.

```
while (true) {
    try {
        // line 1 (something that might throw an exception)
        break;
    } catch (SocketException se) {
        // handle the error
    }
}
```

If the code in your `try` block executes successfully, the `break` will be encountered, and your loop will exit. If a `SocketException` is thrown, execution will return the the top of the `while` loop and your `line 1` will be repeated.

If you only want to retry a fixed number of times (to avoid being stuck indefinitely), then you could use a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop.